# Typescript empty object for react state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a type for a specific object that can be empty, let's start at the bottom and work our way up to the React class.

**Note**: I am not using hooks, but even f your answer was in hooks, it can't be that hard to translate.

We first need to define the state for our class:

```
export default interface CharacterInventoryTabsState {
    table: string;

    dark_tables: boolean;

    loading: boolean;

    inventory: Inventory | {};
}
```

The issue is the `inventory` property. So lets look at the `Inventory` type:

```
export default interface Inventory {

    equipped: InventoryDetails[] | [];

    inventory: InventoryDetails[] | [];

    quest_items: InventoryDetails[] | [];

    usable_items: InventoryDetails[] | [];

    savable_sets: SetDetails[] | [];

    usable_sets: SetDetails[] | [];

    sets: {[key: string]: InventoryDetails[] | []}

    set_equipped: boolean;
}
```

The inventory object is made up of other objects and their associated types. Fantastic. So lets look at the react class:

The below is just a snippit of the class.

```
export default class CharacterInventoryTabs extends React.Component<any, CharacterInventoryTabsState> {

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

     // ...
 
    this.state = {
        table: 'Inventory',
        dark_tables: false,
        loading: true,
        inventory: {} as Inventory, // I saw this trick to initialize "empty objects"
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    watchForDarkModeInventoryChange(this);

    (new Ajax()).setRoute('character/'+this.props.character_id+'/inventory').doAjaxCall('get', (result: AxiosResponse) => {
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            inventory: result.data, // => Here we initialize inventory but ...
        });
    }, (error: AxiosError) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

// ... some where in the render method we do:

render() {
    // ... Loader logic so we would never access the state until loading was set to false.
    return(
        <InventoryTable dark_table={this.state.dark_tables} character_id=. {this.props.character_id} inventory={this.state.inventory.inventory} />
    );
}
```

}

The issue is simple: *Property 'inventory' does not exist on type '{} | Inventory'.   Property 'inventory' does not exist on type '{}'.*

Well duh, its not initialized till after the ajax call and I have a "if loading show the loader jazz" so it would "technically be initialized after the ajax call" but how do I make typescript be quiet about this, aside from the dreaded: `any`.

I saw the trick of `const var = {} as Type` in another stack question related to this, but alas it does not seem to work for me.

**What is the correct way to handle a situation like this?**

Comment: *I saw the trick of const var = {} as Type in another stack question related to this, but alas it does not seem to work for me.* -- some explanation about why it didn't work for you might help.

Comment: I've used `<Partial<Inventory>>` in some situations before. Not sure if it's suitable for you here, but something to maybe look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Well, first of all get rid of any `as`es - they're you pinky-swearing that "I know perfectly well what I'm doing with my types".
2. Make the type for the inventory state field something like `inventory: Inventory | null`, and initialize it with `null`.
3. In your render function, destructure `inventory` into a local: `const {inventory} = this.state;`. (This helps TS with inference.)
4. `if(inventory === null) return <Loading />;`
5. The if/return will help TypeScript narrow the type of `inventory` for the rest of the render function; after all, if it's not `null`, it can only be a real Inventory.

Unless you need `loading` for anything else, you could also drop it from state, since you can tell whether you're loading based on just whether `inventory !== null`.

Comment: You sir have simplified my confusion. Hahahaha. Thank you - I dont know why I didn't just say null to begin with, probably because I expect an object ... hahaha. Thanks again :D

Comment: @TheWebs You're welcome - glad I could help! In general, though... there are very, very few places where you need any `as`es, if the rest of your program is type-sound, so I'd do my best to avoid them :)